# Laravel Controllers without Routes (CodeIgniter-way)

Tags: codeigniter, laravel, laravel-routing

I was using CodeIgniter for a while and now moved to Laravel.

When creating a Controller in CodeIgniter, it automatically uses /controller/method as a route. e.g.

```
class Users extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        // Something here
    }
    public function view() {
        // Something here
    }
}
```

Now we can go to `http://example.com/users/index` or `http://example.com/users` (`index` is optionnal) and `http://example.com/users/view`. Without the need to create routes in `routes.php` instead.

In Laravel we are used to do this `Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');` in `routes.php`.

Is there a way to do it as CodeIgniter? I mean without writing each time which URI uses which Controller?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is!

http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#implicit-controllers

It isn't *exactly* the same, but you can really just prepend each of your method names with 'get' and it should work quite happily.

Define the route using the Route::controller method:

> Route::controller('users', 'UserController');

Comment: Oh, great! Thank you very much! That's even better than CodeIgniter's version.